# c++ dll using classes cause compile error

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I'm attempting to compile a dll using classes. For instance, I have a class like so:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void hello();
};
```

C++:

```
void MyClass::hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

And in my dll code, I call it like you normally would:

```
#include <hello.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void hello()
{
    MyClass c;
    c.hello();
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass()'
undefined reference to `MyClass::hello()'
```

The command I use to build is: `g++ -shared -Iheaders -o hello.dll interop.cpp`

I use the same class on Linux to compile a .so and no errors, and works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `g++ -shared -Iheaders -o hello.dll interop.cpp hello.cpp`

Comment: Meh, I didn't even think about that...now I feel like a moron :p Thank you

Comment: No problem :-) Happens to the best.

Comment: No, I couldn't even get to outputing objects since it spit out compiling errors. Kerrek SB's suggestion helped.